# Запрос SQL количества посещений в разрезе недели

Tags: sql

Есть таблица посещений:

1. Дата
2. Имя (к примеру)

Хочу видеть в разрезе недели количество посещений, попробовал таким запросом:

```
SELECT week(a.date) AS 'неделя/года',
                   c.id = 1 AS 'Х',
                   c.id = 2 AS 'Г',
                   c.id = 3 AS 'Т',
                   c.id = 4 AS 'Пд',
                   c.id = 5 AS 'Пс',
                   count(*)
      FROM vizits a, direction c
     WHERE a.direction_id = c.id
GROUP BY week(a.date)
```

Получаю результат:

```
(н/г,   Х,   Г,   Т,   Пд,  Пс, count(*))
('40', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4'),
('42', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '3'),
('43', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '4')
```

Но результат не верен( сумма правильна, а разрез нет.

Comment: Добавьте структуру второй таблицы... А лучше дампы обеих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неплохо было бы упомянуть СУБД в которой вы это делаете. В MSSQL, например такие номера в принципе не проходят (если есть `GROUP BY`, все вытаскиваемые поля должны быть либо в группировке, либо в агрегации).

Но, вот что вам примерно нужно:

```
SELECT week(a.date) AS 'неделя/года',
                   SUM(c.id = 1) AS 'Х',
                   SUM(c.id = 2) AS 'Г',
                   SUM(c.id = 3) AS 'Т',
                   SUM(c.id = 4) AS 'Пд',
                   SUM(c.id = 5) AS 'Пс',
                   count(*)
      FROM vizits a, direction c
     WHERE a.direction_id = c.id
GROUP BY week(a.date)
```

То есть внутри каждой группы нужно просуммировать единички которые возвращает вам оператор сравнения за каждое посещение.

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: какая все-таки СУБД?

Comment: СУБД - MySql

Answer (score 1):

Интуиция подсказывает, что результат должен быть таким:

```
SELECT week(a.date) AS 'неделя/года',
                   SUM(case c.id when 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Х',
                   SUM(case c.id when 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Г',
                   SUM(case c.id when 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Т',
                   SUM(case c.id when 4 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Пд',
                   SUM(case c.id when 5 then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Пс',
                   count(*)
      FROM vizits a, direction c
     WHERE a.direction_id = c.id
GROUP BY week(a.date)
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже подходит