# Вывод таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Интересная задача. Короче, есть лог `(TABLE log)` вида:

```
id |NAME |    DATE    | PROFIT
---+-----+------------+-------   
 1 | BEN |'2011-01-01'|   3
 2 | ANN |'2011-01-01'|   1
 3 | JOY |'2011-01-05'|   7
 4 | BEN |'2011-01-03'|   2
....
 ? | PAUL|'2011-12-31'|   5
```

`BEN, ANN` и т.д. это клерки. `DATE` и `PROFIT` -- прибыль которую они принесли в этот день. Важно! Все поля не `NULL`. `id` - `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Предположим, пришел дядя `PETYA` и сказал: "хочу отчет от `2011-01-03` по `2011-01-10`".
Примерно такого вида:

```
    |'2011-01-01'|'2011-01-02'|'2011-01-03'|...|'2011-01-10'
----+------------+------------+------------+---+------------
 ANN|      1     |    NULL    |      6     |...|    NULL 
 BEN|      3     |      2     |    NULL    |...|      9 
....
 TOM|    NULL    |    NULL    |      5     |...|      4
```

Т.е. здесь перечислены все клерки без повторений и в точности все даты которые просил ШЕФ. Понятно, если заработать в этот день не удалось, то в отчете `NULL` (или пусто или `&nbsp`).

Теперь вопрос как этот отчет вывести в таблицу с помощью `PHP`. Имена всех работников известны заранее, а даты могут всегда добавляться в конец лога. Просьба акцентировать внимание на `PHP` (вплоть до `echo "<tr></tr>"`))), ибо 3-й день уже не могу разобраться с фунциями вывода `mysql_fetch_array` и `mysql_result`.

P.S. Задачу сам придумал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут всё просто. Первым делом формируем массив дат.

```
$from = '2011-01-03';
$to = '2011-01-10';

if ($from > $to) {
    $tmp = $from; $from = $to; $to = $tmp;
}

$st = strtotime($from . ' 12:00:00');
$dates = array();
while (true) {
    $cd = date('Y-m-d', $st);
    $dates[] = $cd;
    if ($cd >= $to) {
        break;
    }
    $st = strtotime('+1 day', $st);
}
print_r($dates);
```

Это выведет:

`Array
(
    [0] => 2011-01-03
    [1] => 2011-01-04
    [2] => 2011-01-05
    [3] => 2011-01-06
    [4] => 2011-01-07
    [5] => 2011-01-08
    [6] => 2011-01-09
    [7] => 2011-01-10
)`

Важно что бы даты в то место попадали именно в том формате что указано.

Далее собираем информацию из базы:

```
$data = array();

$res = query('select * from log where `DATE` >= '.q($from).' and `DATE` <= '.q($to));
while ($r = fetch($res)) {
    $data[$r['NAME']][$r['DATE']] = $r['PROFIT'];
}
free($res);
```

тут используются функции query, fetch и q

По воводу первых двух я думаю вы догадаетесь, а вот q - это квотирование строки. В самом простом случае она будет выглядеть так:

```
funciton q($str)
{
    return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($str)."'";
}
```

Поехали дальше. Выводим всё то что мы тут понасобирали.

```
$t = '<table>';
foreach ($data as $name => $d) {
    $t .= '<tr>';
    $t .= '<th>'.$name.'</th>';
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $t .= '<td>'.(isset($d[$date]) ? $d[$date] : 'NULL').'</td>';
    }
}
$t .= '</table>';
echo $t;
```

Вот и всё ...

зы: я не проверял, но поидее должно получится то что вы хотели :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вышло как и хотел. Правда пришлось немного подфиксить момент, где выбираются клерки..

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое, что вы можете сделать, это создать двухмерный массив. В строках - сотрудники, в столбцах даты. Пройтись по набору данных и для каждой исходной строки находить соответствующую ячейку массива и плюсовать в нее значение PROFIT.

Вариант посложнее (хотя кому как) - зная диапазон дат, сформировать SQL запрос, который вернет уже готовый кросстаб в нужном виде. Это делается примерно так как рассматривалось [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/46294/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-sql-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8). Только там брался разрез по видам работ, а у вас будет по датам.